# How to create view's in meteor using mongoDb

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am new to meteor and my requirement is to create views as to create a document in mongo and which is share by multiple parents . So, how to create a view to share same document by two or more parents logically not physically.

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Meteor doesn't quite work that way. You will need to use a framework as a view layer such a blaze, react or angular. And to change views use a router.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor does not have View concept on the database level.

You define your data in mongo collection and you make them available to client side using publications.

By default, publication return results from one collection.
if you want to return data based on 'joins' between collection , you can use this package : [reywood:publish-composite](https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite) so that when data change in the collection, your whole publication will get recomputed and you will have new version of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Mongo view in Meteor like so:

```
// Use a collection that already exists that you're already using
const SomeCollection = new Mongo.Collection('some_collection');

// Then grab the raw db handler
// @link http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Db.html
const db = SomeCollection.rawDatabase();

// Unfortunately, this driver doesn't support the `db.createView` method
// So let's use `db.createCollection` instead
// @link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/#db.createCollection
db.createCollection('orderView', { // name of the view to create
  viewOn: 'order', // name of source collection from which to create the view
  pipeline: [{
    $lookup: {
      from: 'customer',
      localField: 'customerId',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'customerDoc',
    } }, { $unwind: '$customerDoc' }
  ],
}).then((view) => {
  // do stuff with your view
});
```

`db` operations are handled with promises so you may want to use `async` and `await` to keep things tidy.

```
const createView = async (viewName, viewOn, pipeline) =>
  await db.createCollection(viewName, { viewOn, pipeline });

// Someplace else in your code
const someMethod = async () => {
  // ...
  const myView = await createView('orderView', 'order', [{
    $lookup: {
      from: 'customer',
      localField: 'customerId',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'customerDoc',
    } }, { $unwind: '$customerDoc' }
  ]);
  // ...
};
```